# How to read contents of a huge xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want read a large dblp.xml file in c# because its a huge file, which can not load into memory. I query to take some data from this huge file. how can i read/get it.

```
<phdthesis mdate="2012-04-18" key="phd/tw/Chang2008">
  <author>Fengming Chang</author>
  <title>Learning accuracy from limited data: </title>
  <year>2008</year>
  <school>Tainan, National Cheng Kung Univ.</school>
  <pages>1-67</pages>
  <isbn>978-3-8364-8603-3</isbn>
  <note type="dnb">http://d-nb.info/989267156</note>
</phdthesis>
```

How can i read from a huge xml file using c# not loading all xml file in memory?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4 - for best performance you should be using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) as it *streams* the document instead of loading the full thing into memory.

The code you refer to uses `XmlReader` for the actual querying so should be reasonably quick on large documents.

**Sample Code**

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(filename);
reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
while (reader.Read())
{
    // your code here.
}
```

Comment: There is a reason we block LMGTFY links. Having to obfuscate the link should have been your first clue. If it's a poor quality question, just don't answer it. If it's a duplicate, just vote to close.

Comment: Okay. My bad. Cudnt resist to put it though. Anyways will be careful hence forth :)